# How to change field as a url parameter dynamically in Ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a field "amount" on the frontend (ReactJS):

```
export const AmountField = {
  headerName: "Amount",
  field: "amount",
  ...
}
```

I need to send the field name "amount__abs" as a url parameter to the backend. I need to sort by absolute value. How can I change the field name dynamically in Ag-Grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the field of a column dynamically, you have to update the column definition for that column (or add a new column entirely).

See the documentation on [Updating Column Definitions](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-updating-definitions/#updating-column-definitions).